# Confidence interval fit around GAMMA and BETA distribution

Tags: r, regression, confidence-interval, gamlss

So currently I am using the new GAMLSS package and have plotted my model as shown in the photo. The blue line is my estimate (which I want to use at my point of estimate) when attempting to create a confidence interval. I used the family distribution "BE" and "GA" but somehow all my CI are always way off than the results I am able to produce in SAS. I was wondering if anyone could show me how to create a 95% CI around my set estimate (the blue line).[image]

Here is an example of one I Completed with lognormal:
[image]